# How much can I scale the image's dimension after a quality scale?

Tags: android, image, bitmap

Hi guys this is a brand new topic and I'm really a rooky in image stuff.

I need to upload on my webserver an image from user's smartphone.
So before the upload operation I downscale the image quality to a JPEG with 60% of quality.

After that quality compression can I also downscale the image pixel size without losing a lot of overall quality?

Is there an equation that can give me the % of pixel downscale I can do if I know the dimension in pixels of the source image and how much I've scaled down the quality?

Thank you very much, sorry if the question is stupid or obvious but as I said this is not my main topic.

Comment: A consideration: JPEG isn't known for being a QUALITY format, since its compression is **LOSSY**. 60% seems **too little** to me. 75% quality would be the MINIMUM acceptable for me (100% being the optimum). Just keep in mind that **EACH TIME you re-save a JPG image you LOOSE QUALITY**...

Comment: why dont you try it in photoshop?

Comment: @Leonidos I've to do that operation on runtime in my android app :)

Comment: @StErMi you can do the same compression in photoshop and check quality of resulting images. If it's ok, than it will be ok in android.
If you want to downscale images, that downscale it first then compress with JPEG.

Comment: There's no clear answer without understanding your requirements a little more. What will the image be used for? Does it need to be high quality? As @Leonidos says: maybe experiment a little to see what meets your requirements. If the reason for reducing image size is your users' data usage then consider different policies for GSM vs. WiFi. If the reason is to reduce server load then consider doing it server-side as you can tweak it without having to update your client app.

Answer (score 0):

The quality percentage in JPEG is a meaningless (at best qualitative) figure. JPEG "quality" values translate into quantization table selection. Some JPEG implementations use a numeric range to scale a base quantization table.  The resulting quality of the compressed image spends upon the nature of the image being compressed.